# Should I work in the blade.php or use a component for a Laravel + Vue web app

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm building a Narrow Casting System that displays tickets from a 3rd party API. The backend is handled with Laravel, and the frontend with Vue.

I am wondering if I should get all the components in the blade.php file or make a Vue component which loads them individually (A wrapper for the components, sort of), and then loading a single component in the blade.php.

Comment: This depends on what you want to do. Do you want to use Vue to make a SPA or do you still want to use blade? I think this question is too broad or atleast there isn't enough info to give a real answer

Comment: Its a narrow cast. Its not going to have any navigation whatsoever. Just a screen displaying some data.

Answer (score 0):

Loading components individually give you the benefit of lazy loading (async loading), making you app load fast and perform better, saving requests loading a single bundle with all you need.

Putting all components in a blade file is not readable, hard to maintain, you can't say if that component is a dependency of another or is an entry point.

Comment: So you recommend making a component named App.vue, where the data is fetched and making other components to display the data?

Comment: Exactly! This way App.vue is your application entry point. Other way is to create a main.js file where you put your Vue instance and import global components, helpers and other stufs.